# Why is this object mutating during a method call?

Tags: java

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int birthYear;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthYear = 1970;
    }

    public int getBirthYear() {
        return this.birthYear;
    }

    public void setBirthYear(int birthYear) {
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name + " (" + this.birthYear + ")";
    }
}

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person first = new Person("First");

        System.out.println(first);
        youthen(first);
        System.out.println(first);

        Person second = first;
        youthen(second);

        System.out.println(first);
    }

    public static void youthen(Person person) {
        person.setBirthYear(person.getBirthYear() + 1);
    }
}
```

My tutorial says the output will be:

```
First (1970)
First (1971)
First (1972)
```

I can follow the code up until the second Person object is created. Then I don't see why calling the youthen method on the second Person object is changing the first Person object.

The way I see it, there are two Person objects. We changed the birth year of Person first, we then copied Person first's instance variable values to Person second, and then we acted on Person second's instance variable values using the youthen method, while Person first hasn't changed since the previous method call to it. I expected the final print method to return

```
First (1971)
```

Comment: Because second has a same link in memory as first does

Answer (score 6):

> up until the second Person object is created

Nope.  This code only ever creates one `Person` object.  Right here:

```
new Person("First")
```

At no other point is the `Person` constructor invoked, so at no other point is another `Person` object created.  What you have are multiple *references* to the *same* `Person` object:

```
Person second = first;
```

As an analogy, imagine that you have a house and you write down the address to that house on two pieces of paper.  One person, using their piece of paper, goes to the house and changes something about it.  (Paints it a new color, for example.)  The second person then uses their piece of paper to go to the house and they see the new color.  Because there's only one house, no matter how many people know its address.

To create a second `Person`, re-invoke the constructor:

```
Person second = new Person("Second");
```

Comment: I really like the house/address analogy, thanks!

Comment: Thank you! It did cross my mind that there was never a new Person statement so no second object was created. This makes sense. So now I'm just confused as to what the point of this would be. Why not just invoke youthen(first)? Can you give me a real world code example where adding a second reference to the same object solves a problem?

Comment: @gfries: One example would be in your own `youthen()` method.  If a new reference to the same object wasn't created and instead an entirely new object was created, that method wouldn't do anything.  Its `person` variable would be a new object.  It would set a value on that new object and then return, making no modifications to the original object.  Or when you call methods on `Person` itself, what would `this` refer to if not the same object as the variable on which you called the method?  Silently duplicating objects would have drastic consequences, crippling the language.